# Not able to use npm cli in a github workflows

Tags: github, npm, workflow

I want to use a npm cli utility (this [one](https://github.com/sindresorhus/capture-website-cli)), inside a bash script and to run it via a github workflow.

This is my basic script:

```sh
folder="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

mkdir -p "$folder"/rawdata
mkdir -p "$folder"/processing

npm list -g --depth=0

rm "$folder"/rawdata/"$reg".png
capture-website --delay 5 --full-page --width 1280 --height  720 --output  "$folder"/rawdata/"$reg".png "https://ondata.github.io/vaccinipertutti/?area=SIC"
```

I run it using this github workflow (it's Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS), in which I set capture-website-cli installation in this way:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
npm install -g capture-website
```

But when the script runs I have this error:

```
./test.sh: line 13: capture-website: command not found
```

It seems that it has been not installed in `~/.npm-global`.
If I run  `find /home/runner -executable -name capture-website` I have

```
/home/runner/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/capture-website
```

Do you have some advice to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to differentiate between:

- [`capture-website`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-website)
- [`sindresorhus/capture-website-cli`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/capture-website-cli) which provide a CLI (commannd-line interface) way to use that npm *library* (library means: no executable in `.npm-global/bin`)

You need to install the latter in your runner `$PATH`.

```
npm install --global capture-website-cli
```